# Check if user input is a number

Tags: c#

I want to check if user's input is a number. If yes I want the function to keep running else  want to alert him and run it again.

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Concat("choose your action" ,Environment.NewLine ,
                                "1.Deposit", Environment.NewLine,
                                "2.Withdraw", Environment.NewLine,
                                "3.CheckAccount"));
string c = Console.ReadLine();
int value = Convert.ToInt32(c);

if (value==char.IsLetterOrDigit(value)) //<----- no good why?
{
    switch (value)
    {
        case 1:
            Deposit();
            return;
        case 2:
            Withdraw();
            return;
        case 3:
            CheckAccount();
            return;
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for using `String.Concat` mate! There's an operator for that, namely the string concatenation operator `+`, which is optimized into a call to `String.Concat`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just use:

```
string c = Console.ReadLine();
int value;
if (int.TryParse(c, out value)) { /*Operate*/ }
```

EDIT: to adapt the code to the author's comment:

```
if (int.TryParse(c, out value) && value >= 1 && value <= 3) { /*Operate*/ }
```

Comment: how do i add a check to see that the number is between 1-3 and its not a float or double?

Comment: @user1942298 `int.TryParse` will return `false` in case the number is not an integer. I've edited my post to adapt it to your second request.

Comment: @Mir: why you have used `out` here? Is it allowed to omit it ?

Comment: @Destructor out is the output that you are going to use if the parsing(converting string to int) is successful.

Answer (score 1):

int value = Convert.ToInt32(c);
this is going to fail if c is not a string consisting of integers only.
use try catch to handle this situation.

Comment: I'd use `TryParse`, it's much faster. I haven't tested on .NET but Mono gave me 649 milliseconds for your method and 47 milliseconds for `TryParse` for this test: http://pastebin.com/HfLjqTqg.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Write:
`string chooseNum = Console.ReadLine();
int val;\\in which the value will pass
if (!checkNum )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Its not a Number");
}*\\ We Will Directly get out of it if its not a Number*
else
{ 
if (val >= 1 && val <=3)
        switch (val)
    {
        case 1:
            Deposit();
            return;
        case 2:
            Withdraw();
            return;
        case 3:
            CheckAccount();
            return;
    }
}
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Number Must be b/w 1 and 3");
}
 `
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**