# If user input is not a number

Tags: c#, string, integer, converters

This is a very simple script I am trying to figure out and I have been looking for a simple answer and can't find it in the forums or in my C# book.

```
Console.Write("Enter a Number\n");
int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); //convert code to an integer

if (!Int32.IsNumber(input)) //if not a whole number input give an error
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not an integer");
}
```

It's just that simple what I'm trying to do.  This is a snippet from a bigger code.

Comment: What's your question? Have you tested the code? Does it work? If not, please post the exact error message you get or behaviour you see.

Comment: take a look at `int.TryParse` this is probably what you are looking for. It  convert the the string to an integer an told you if conversion was successful or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if user input is a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304591/check-if-user-input-is-a-number)

Comment: [How to identify if a string is a number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894263/how-to-identify-if-a-string-is-a-number) [How can I check if a string is a number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733652/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number) [C# testing to see if a string is an integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752499/c-sharp-testing-to-see-if-a-string-is-an-integer) [How to validate user input for whether it's an integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395630/how-to-validate-user-input-for-whether-its-an-integer)

Comment: With C# it won't run because of the debugger, not unless the code is correct.  I will use the TryParse command.  I wasn't sure if that was the only way, but it looks like it is.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Console.Write("Enter a Number\n");
string input = Console.ReadLine(); //get the input
int num = -1;
if (!int.TryParse(input, out num))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not an integer");
}
else
{
   ...
}
```

`Int.TryParse` will return false if the string is not a valid integer and vise versa

Comment: It only works if I do if (!int.TryParse(input, out num)).  A lowercase int, but then it doesn't work right.  It doesn't show the custom error

Comment: Error when using a capital I in 'Int'   "The name 'Int' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @SDJ fixed, use the lower case int instead

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the easiest and best code to get this done from many answers:

```
Console.Write("\nEnter a Whole Number (Such as 12)\n");
string Input = Console.ReadLine();

char firstChar = Input[0];
bool isNumber = Char.IsDigit(firstChar);

if (!isNumber)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Not an integer");
} 
else 
 {
.......
}
```